# List of Chrome Driver preferences - Selenium 4.0

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, download, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking for the equivalent commands to set preferences for Chrome Driver in Selenium.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
        fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.path.abspath(folder_to_save))
        fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                          "application/xapk-package-archive;application/vnd.android.package- 
archive")  # application/octet-stream;application/vnd.android.package-archive;application/zip;
        opts = FirefoxOptions()
        opts.add_argument("--headless")
```

I searched the Selenium Documentation but got lost there somewhere and couldnt find anything about download folders in Chrome.

Help is appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: What is your question, ChromeDriver preferences or preferences for download?

Comment: My focus is on the download preferences but I would also appreciate a list where I can go through all of them.